# CouchDB - passing MapReduce results into second MapReduce function

Tags: performance, couchdb, mapreduce

Rank amateur at both Map/Reduce and CouchDB here. I have a CouchDB populated with ~600,000 rows of data which indicate views of records. My desire is to produce a graph showing hits per record, over the entire data set.

I have implemented Map/Reduce functions to do the grouping, as so:

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.id, doc);
}
```

and:

```
function(key, values) {
    return values.length;
}
```

Now because there's still a fair amount of reduced values and we only want, say, 100 data points on the graph, this isn't very usable. Plus, it takes forever to run.

I could just retrieve every Xth row, but would would be *ideal* would be to pass these reduced results back into another reduce function which takes the mean of its values so I eventually get a nice set of, say, 100 results, which are useful for throwing into a high level overview graph to see distribution of hits.

Is this possible? (and if so, what would the keys be?) Or have I just messed something up in my MapReduce code that's making it grossly non-performant, thus allowing me to do this in my application code? There are only 33,500 results returned.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Two related questions - if the latency is with churning out JSON over the network, is there some facility to do custom JS-based post-processing on the server? Or am I just doing things wrong? Particularly after reading [this article](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/How_to_handle_stats_aggregation), I'm wondering if I either need to pre-aggregate before it gets to CouchDB (which is not going to work, as I always need to see summary of the entire dataset - i.e., not split by time), or use not use CouchDB.

Am I indeed trying to force it into doing something it isn't good at?

Comment: Reading that article again, I suppose that instead of indexing the raw access log data, I can index hits per record per a suitably-granular time period (say, hits per record per day). Will experiment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question:

1. According to [this article](http://www.ibuildings.co.uk/blog/archives/1291-Some-thoughts-on-CouchDB.html), CouchDB doesn't support passing Map/Reduce output as input to another Map/Reduce function, although the article notes that other projects such as [disco](http://discoproject.org/) do support this.
2. Custom server-side processing can be performed by way of CouchDB lists - like, for example, [sorting by value](http://geekiriki.blogspot.co.nz/2010/08/couchdb-using-list-functions-to-sort.html).